# Redirect to Page with ID in Razor Pages

Tags: redirect, .net-core, routes, razor-pages

I'm trying to get my app to redirect to the previous page after it updates the database but I can't seem to figure it out. What's complicating it is that the previous page isn't just a simple page. It's populated with information pulled but a specific row in the database so the URL has

> blah blah blah.../ProjectDetails?id=(the ID number)

I've tried using the Redirect Methods but they aren't as straight forward as I'd hoped. Can someone help me figure out how to go back to the previous page?

**View**

```html
<form method="post">
  <select class="custom-select mb-4 col-6" name="Assignee">
       <option>John</option>
       <option>Jane</option>
       <option>Jim</option>
       <option>Juju</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
  <a class="btn btn-danger" asp-page="./Teamlead">Cancel</a>
</form>
```

**Code Behind**

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int id)
{
   Submission = _SubmissionContext.Submissions
                                .Where(s => s.ID == id).First();
   Submission.AssignedTo = Assignee;
   await _SubmissionContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    
   return RedirectToRoute("./ProjectDetails"); //PROBLEM HERE
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to pass the id to the redirected page. You can use an anonymous type to do that like:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int id)
{
   Submission = _SubmissionContext.Submissions
                            .Where(s => s.ID == id).First();
   Submission.AssignedTo = Assignee;
   await _SubmissionContext.SaveChangesAsync();

   return RedirectToRoute("./ProjectDetails", new { id = Submission.ID });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should try decorating your razor page view at the top with your route attributes like so:

```
@page "{id}"
```

The following link below should help example more about routing parameters:

See [mikesdotnetting.com - routing-in-razor-pages](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/310/routing-in-razor-pages)

#### Adding constraints

From [learnrazorpages.com - Razor Pages Routing](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing#adding-constraints) you can also add this to the razor page

```cs
@page "{id:int}"
```

Comment: I really like the information on this link. Thank you for sharing. But your answer doesn't tell me how I can reroute the code to the previous page. Or maybe I'm just not fully understanding.

Comment: You can try Brad's answer but you will also need to adjust your Get method too when loading that page so that it can accept the id parameter when it re-routes to your page. Try something like:

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int id)
{

}

You can add the @page {id} to the cshtml view so that when you return to that page you can keep that value in your url should you wish to resave the submission again as you're using the default OnPostAsync() post method.